# MediaPlayer.Play method throwing DRM exception?!

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to add background music to my XNA 4-based Windows game. When I do

```
Song bgm = Content.Load<Song>("bgm");
MediaPlayer.Play(bgm);
```

in the `MyGame.LoadContent` method, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message **"Song playback failed. Please verify that the song is not DRM protected. DRM protected songs are not supported for creator games."** The song is in MP3 format and is not protected. I tried using a WAV instead and the result was the same.

It seems [I'm not the only one having this problem](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/79698/482944.aspx). But the closest thing I've found to a solution is "use XACT".

Any ideas?

Edit: Also, why is my code snippet not syntax highlighted? It's highlighted in preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I had uninstalled Windows Media Player. For what it's worth, I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. I reinstalled WMP via the Windows Features dialog and the problem went away immediately. I didn't even have to restart.

Comment: My guess is that XNA and/or DirectX use WMP dlls for the audio playback or DRM checking.

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me was that I was missing the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB capability in my WMAppManifest.xml.

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I created a Mango version of my game, everything is a linked file except this manifest file and the tile icon (the two that cant be linked).  Thanks, this fixed it for me.